# How do I use the command, "t.print" in Python 3.7.2?

Tags: python, printing

I want to print some text, I saw the command "t.print" in a source code file for a course on Udemy. I want to use this command in my projects for fun that I'm doing. How do I use it?

I've tried doing the same command millions of times by simply changing stuff such as font size which is the big thing I want to do right now, but have no clue on how to do it. I would simply just get an error message whenever I put in different.

```
for x in range(10000):
    t.pencolor("White")
    t.pendown()

    t.write(your_name, font = ("Arial", int( (x + 1) / 1), "bold") )
```

It keeps telling me to change the font size but I don't know how to.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ArjunR/Desktop/code 3/s03/SpiralMyName.py", line 16, in <module>
    t.write(your_name, font = ("Arial", "bold") )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 3431, in write
    end = self._write(str(arg), align.lower(), font)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 3403, in _write
    self._pencolor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 597, in _write
    fill = pencolor, font = font)
  File "<string>", line 1, in create_text
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2504, in create_text
    return self._create('text', args, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "bold"
```

Comment: Well, what is the error you are getting? Please include the full error stacktrace because it includes valuable information to help you.

Comment: What is `t`, and how did you get it? What library are you working with? We need more information about the broader context of this problem - what you're trying to accomplish and what you're doing that isn't working.

Comment: I'm trying to use python turtle graphics

Comment: I'm trying to just find out how to use the font size section in the t.print command.

Comment: When I take it out, this error comes up,"

Comment: File "/Users/ArjunR/Desktop/code 3/s03/SpiralMyName.py", line 16, in <module>
    t.write(your_name, font = ("Arial", "bold") )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 3431, in write
    end = self._write(str(arg), align.lower(), font)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 3403, in _write
    self._pencolor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 597, in _write
    fill = pencolor, font = font)
  File "<string>", line 1, in create_text

Comment: Sorry, Couldn't fit it in

Comment: Here I'll break it up

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ArjunR/Desktop/code 3/s03/SpiralMyName.py", line 16, in <module>
    t.write(your_name, font = ("Arial", "bold") )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 3431, in write
    end = self._write(str(arg), align.lower(), font)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 3403, in _write
    self._pencolor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 597, in _write
    fill = pencolor, font = font)

Comment: File "<string>", line 1, in create_text
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2504, in create_text
    return self._create('text', args, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: expected integer but got "bold"

Comment: as said - in question, not in comment

Comment: How are we supposed to read that unformatted error message? Edit the full traceback into the question, the comments are not the right place for that.

Comment: Oh, Sorry!!!!!!

Comment: error shows that you use `font = ("Arial", "bold")` but `turtle` expects `("Arial", size, "bold")`

Comment: by the way: if you use white color in `pencolor()` then you can't see text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import turtle as t
FONTSIZE = 10
FONTSTYLE = ('Arial', FONTSIZE, 'normal')
t.write('Hello World!', font=FONTSTYLE)
t.mainloop()
```

This is how we normally draw using turtle, in your case when you try with ramge(10000) it surely is not a valod font soze, try making the range smaller.

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much

Comment: If it worked please accept the answer so that the question can be assumed closed @ArjunRajdev